# NEAR protocol contract - if condition (after timestamp) for read function - is it possible?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm new student and learning on examples from repo https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-sdk-as.  I am curious will the following work (pseudocode) -

```
function read() { if (currentblock.timestamp > 16344838928374) { return string } }
```

- so i need to know several things

1. How to set "if" condition to read() function, i.e. for instance set a block height or timestamp  before which function should not return string value
2. Is it possible to extract from deployed contract (to know, to hack, read from transaction)  value of string written to contract without calling read() function?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your question but for the second one, if you are looking for something similar to `console.log()`, you can use `logging.log()` to see some value on the terminal.

Comment: I meant already deployed contract